# MAC: Remote Desktop Connection - take over session of active user on client

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I am new to RDP, hence not entirely sure if this is the desired behaviour or not.

I am using RDP on my MAC to connect to clients throughout the office and do minor maintenance on them. Today I noticed that the moment I login via RDP, the currently active user on this machine gets logged off and directed to the Windows 10 Login screen, while RDP starts a new "login" for me where I can control the computer and do what is needed without the user sitting in front of the PC actually seeing what's happening.

Is it possible that instead of logging out the user and keeping him/her at the login screen, I could simply take over the current session running on the PC? I am thinking along the lines of Teamviewer, where the user can see me moving the mouse, clicking on folders, etc. Basically a real "remote control" session if you so want.

Is this achievable via RDP or should I just stick to Teamviewer?

Thanks

Comment: Workstations only have a console session, which doesn't work with shadowing.

Comment: @GregAskew so if I wanted to have the user see what I am doing, my only feasible choice is Teamviewer?

Comment: There's other options in addition to TeamViewer. This isn't a new problem.